# Can content scripts communicate with in-page scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If, for instance, a webpage has some global variable declared in its page, is it possible for a content script to read from it? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something you are looking for.

> Similar to cross-extension messaging, your app or extension can
>   receive and respond to messages from regular web pages.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage